# Similar answer as self standing answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm mainly answering UML tagged questions and as it happens there are a lot of questions being rather similarly - but not identically. So it happens that they get flagged as duplicate and eventually closed. However, I think that similar questions are not a bad thing since they will over time cover a broader audience. So currently there are just the temporary comments where you find the *possible duplicate*.

I was wondering whether there should be something more stable pointing to a related question. SO offers some automatic *Related* references but I never found them useful (really!). But if there were some section with "see also" edited by a human that would probably be more trustworthy.

I just put that here as a thought. No idea whether someone else has already suggested something similar. Also, I have no idea how such a link section could look like.

Comment: "*But if there were some section with "see also" edited by a human that would probably be more trustworthy.*" posting a link as a comment (or in an answer) will create an entry on the side under "Linked" https://i.imgur.com/Kq26wkO.png It's not curated, as it captures all links in any comment, not only things relevant to the question but it's closer to what you mentioned. I often comment with "Related: <links>" that will help discoverability when the linked questions aren't direct duplicates.

Comment: @VLAZ Honestly, I did not know about that. However, a comment is volatile and i was asking for something stable.

Comment: as long they don't have negative score and none answer, the stay alive forever(ok mods can delete them)

Comment: @nbk I was always told that a comment is volatile. The poster can delete is at will, the mods can do and I don't know what all those robots do that lurk around. Anyhow, doesn't seem that anybody is getting my point. So be it.

Comment: nbk seems to be confusing comments for answers. Comments cannot be downvoted, and consequently don't roomba. (Answers admittedly don't roomba either; only questions do.) Comments are indeed volatile; or as they're also referred to, third class citizens. They also have a substantially wider range of removal reasons

Comment: @Zoe i am clearly referring to questions and **not the comments**

Comment: That was not even remotely clear from your comment, as proven by the two subsequential comments from two different people thinking you were talking about the comments.

Comment: @qwerty_so as I said, it's not a perfect solution. I fully agree we probably need something more formal and more under user control. For example, we don't necessarily need every single link in the Q&A part of "Links" - some of them might not be relevant to the question. However, the Links section is what we have right now. I was just letting you know of this current system.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, thanks for the hint. I really was not aware of that. Anyhow, in my opinion that is far from being perfect. But since the question here is getting more down than up votes I'll call it a day. Have a nice one...

Answer (score 4):

This feature already exists. Just add a comment with a link to another question or answer on this site and it will appear in the "Linked" list on the right hand side of the question.